# Pasar Datasource a un SubReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Como puedo pasar el Datasource de un Report a un Subreport(el cual es otro Report), el sub report tiene unos fields donde necesita de una conexión para cargar unos datos, por lo que esos datos a la hora de compilar el report principal se compila bien, pero los datos del subreport que necesita de una conexión a BBDD no se muestran, se muestran los parametros y tal, pero los otros no.

Comment: me gustaría que en vez de poneros a corregir la pregunta, ayudéis, si no no molestéis , enserio.

Answer (score 0):

En las propiedades del subreport, desde el report principal puedes establecerle la propiedad "Connection type" y "Connection expression" (pasándole el parámetro REPORT_CONNECTION, si se trata de una conexión a bbdd).